# Finding $\csc\theta$ from $\sin\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question about trigonometric identities.

> Suppose I am given $\sin\theta= -0.1658$ and I am asked to find $csc\theta$.

When I type this in my calculator as $\csc(1/-0.1658)$ my graphing calculator returns $4.01$, when I round it to the nearest hundredth.

Yet the answer is $-6.03$ when it is rounded to the nearest hundredth.

> Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

I have set my graphing calculator in angle mode degrees and at approximate for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$\csc x = \frac{1}{\sin x}$, so $\sin x = \frac{1}{\csc x}$ (where $\sin x, \csc x \ne 0$).

Your assumption that $\sin x = \csc \left(1/x \right)$ is not necessarily true for all $x$.

Comment: How would I get to the answer -6.03? The work demonstrated for the answer is the calculation input as cscθ = 1/-0.1658 then it shows the solution cscθ is approximately -6.03. That is all it tells me, I am aware that sine and co-secant are reciprocals.

Comment: thanks for helping I figured out the problem I was having. I kept putting csc in front of θ in my calculator.